# What is right way to show folder usage in megabytes

Tags: linux, du

I'm using `du -bs` to count folder size.

```
du -bs /folder
```

Result is **96342835** in Bytes... so in MB is it (/1024/1024) **91,87MB**.

OK, but when I use

```
du -hs /folder
```

Result is different. **99MB** 
Or

```
 du -s taxikondrat.cz/
```

100980 KBytes = **98,61MB**

I tried different methods. In every I got different results. E.g.

```
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat --print='%s\n' | awk '{total+=$1} END {print total}'
```

I got 96059200 bytes, so **91,60MB**

```
ls -ARgo "$@" | awk '{q += $3} END {print q}'
```

96338739 bytes, so **91,87 MB.** After rounding is same, but in bytes little different.

As a cherry on the cake is Google :) 
[image]

So, what is true? Why this differences, and what method is to most accurate count?

Comment: What is real-world problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are comparing apples and oranges.

Please note that `ls -s` will give the size of a file based on the length of the actual data in the file.

By default the `du` command will give a size based **disk usage**. Since disk space gets allocated in blocks, and the lengths of  files are hardly ever  integer multiples of the block size, you end up with a block that's only partially filled with data but which can't be used by another file.
In other words, if your file-system has a blocksize of 512 bytes, a file of 1 byte length will take up 512 bytes on disk, the same as a file of 511 bytes. A file of 513 bytes will take up 2 blocks and 1024 bytes of disk space.

The total sum `du file` disk usages will almost always be more than the sum of `ls -s file` file sizes, especially when you have many (small) files and/or very large block sizes.

Using the `du -b` switch will NOT count blocks, but behave like `ls -s`:

> **`-b`**  equivalent to `--apparent-size --block-size=1`
>   **`--apparent-size`**
>    print  apparent sizes, rather than disk usage; although the apparent size is usually smaller, it may be larger due to holes in ('sparse') files, internal frag‐
>                 mentation, indirect blocks, and the like
>   **`-h, --human-readable`**
>                 print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)

`du -sh` will convert the total number of blocks to a human readable format,
`du -bh` will print the sum of apparent sizes, in human readable format.

In my Maildir, with many small files that differs quite a bit:

```
$ du -bs cur/
84088436    cur/
$ du -s cur/
91800   cur/
$ du -sh cur/
90M cur/
$ du -bh cur/
81M cur/
```

**EDIT** With regards to converting to human readable output and megabytes, please don't overlook the whole *"controversy'* of human readable in SI decimal prefixes versus binary multiples, powers of 1000 versus  powers of 1024.

See for background this page: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Block-size.html on how GNU utilities such as `ls` and `du` display them.

The capital <kbd>M</kbd> in `du -h` output stands for 1,048,576 bytes.

Comment: Note that `du -b` will also report the "real" length of the file.

Comment: This is only the tip of the iceberg (but already complicated enough). There are also such exotic things as filesystems where "tails" of files (i.e. the last couple of bytes that are too small to fill an entire block) can share a block. (E.g. Reiserfs.) In that case, the tail blocks may be counted multiple times toward each file, and how you define the size of a single file in blocks is non-obvious. Then, there are sparse files, where the content of the file is larger than its representation on disk. The same goes for filesystems supporting compression. On filesystems with de-duplication, a …

Comment: … block may be part of more than one file; again, how do you sensibly define "size in blocks" in that case?

Comment: Indeed there are additional complexities but simplified the disk usage is not expected to be equal to the size of the data. - For `du` the block size is usually simply set to 1024 bytes by default at compile time, completely regardless of how the underlying file system is configured

Comment: **TL;DR:** To just output real size on MB: `du -sbm` (replace m for k for kilobytes).